# $this -> Form -> end () does not process options array correctly

Tags: php, forms, cakephp-1.3, cakephp

I have a problem with the Form helper in CakePHP 1.3. The form opening and inputs are generated correctly, however, my Form -> end () function doesn't do what I expect (and want) it to do.

This is my code for the end tag:

```
<?php echo $this -> Form -> end (array (
                                         'value'  => 'registreer',
                                         'id'     => 'register_button'
                                       )
                                ) ?>
```

This is the way the CakePHP API describes the use of the Form helper. However, it doesn't work and Cake just substitutes my options with the defaults.

When I change my code to `$this -> Form -> end ('registreer')` the value is set to 'registreer', but I really need to set an ID for this input, so I need the array to work.

I have looked through the Cake 1.3 Book and the API and I searched Google. Unfortunately Google's mostly gives me Cake 1.2 search results so I can't find an answer to my question online.

Does any of you guys have any idea how to get my form closing correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mmm, I fixed the problem using another way of creating the submit button:

    `echo $this -> Form -> submit ('registreer', array ('id' => 'register_button'));
    echo $this -> Form -> end ();`

This also does the trick. However, I'd still like to know why the code in my original question doesn't work because that's the way the API and the Book tell me how to do it. Can anyone explain what I did wrong in the first place?

Also, why can't I answer my own question for 8 hours.. Now the code that gives the solution isn't formatted correctly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit unclear in the documentation, but You have to specify the `label` option to the array.

```
echo $this->Form->end(array(
  'label' => 'registreer',
  'id' => 'register_button'
  ));
```

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1389/Closing-the-Form

http://api13.cakephp.org/class/form-helper#method-FormHelperend

Comment: Cool! That explains my problem :) Thanks for your answer!